# arparse python argument from directory

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse, positional-operator

I have a file structure like this:

`project/
    main_prog.py
    tools/
       script.py
       md_script/
          __init__.py
          md_script.py`

I search in tools for local python modules. In this example it's md_script. And i want to use it as positional argument like install in my code, but when i use it, I'v got an error:

```
./jsh.py md_script
usage: jsh.py [-h] {install,call,list,log,restore} ... [md_script]
jsh.py: error: invalid choice: 'md_script' (choose from 'install', 'call', 'list', 'log', 'restore')
```

python3.4 on ubuntu14.10
Here is my code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='jsh.py',
    description='Some help.', epilog='Example of usage: some help')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
parser_install = subparsers.add_parser('install', help = 'Install new project.')
parser_install.add_argument('install', nargs='?', help = 'Name of project to be installed')
if os.path.isdir(full/path/to/tools/):
   name_arg = next(os.walk(full/path/to/tools))[1]
   tools_arg = parser.add_argument_group('Tools', 'Modules from tools')
   for element in name_arg:
      tools_arg.add_argument(element, nargs='?', help='md_script description')
args = parser.parse_args()
try:
  if not len(sys.argv) > 1:
     parser.print_help()
  elif 'install' in args:
     do_some_stuff
  elif element in args:
     do_some_md_script_stuff
  else:
     parser.print_help()
```

Answer (score 2):

The `usage` line shows what's wrong:

```
usage: jsh.py [-h] {install,call,list,log,restore} ... [md_script]
```

You need to use something like

```
jsh.py install md_script
```

You specified subparsers, so you have to give it a subparser name.

---

From the `usage` it also looks like you created other subparsers, `call`, `list`, etc that you don't show in the code.

You also define positional arguments after creating subparser.  That's where the `[md_script]` comes from.  Be careful about making a lot of `nargs='?'` positionals (including the argument for the `install` subparser).  This could make things confusing for your users.  In fact it seems to confusing you.  Remember that `subparser` is in effect a positional argument (one that requires 1 string).

I'd suggest experimenting with a simplier parser before creating one this complicated.

---

So from your comments and examples I see that you goal is let the user name a module, so your script can invoke it in some way or other.  For that populating the subparsers with these names makes sense.

I wonder why you also create an optional positional argument with the same name:

```
module_pars = subparsers.add_parser(element, help = 'Modules from tools')
module_pars.add_argument(element, nargs='?', help=element+' description')
```

Is that because you are using the presence of the attribute as evidence that this subparser was invoked?

```
elif element in args:
    do_some_md_script_stuff
```

The `argparse` documentation has a couple of other ideas.

> One particularly effective way of handling sub-commands is to combine the use of the add_subparsers() method with calls to set_defaults() so that each subparser knows which Python function it should execute.

and

> However, if it is necessary to check the name of the subparser that was invoked, the dest keyword argument to the add_subparsers() call will work:

These avoid the messiness of a '?' positional argument, freeing you to use subparser arguments for real information.

```
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='module')
....
for element in name_arg:
    # module_pars = 'parser_'+element   # this does nothing
    module_pars = subparsers.add_parser(element, help = 'Modules from tools')
    module_pars.set_defaults(func = do_some_md_script_stuff)
    # or module_pars.set_default(element='I am here')
    module_pars.add_argument('real_argument')
```

Now you can check:

```
if args.module='md_script':
    do_some_md_script_stuff(args)
```

or

```
if hasattr(args, 'func'):
    func(args)
```

With the alternative `set_defaults`, your original test should still work:

```
if element in args:
    do_some_md_script_stuff
```

Comment: So i should use not group parser, but next subparsers? For each modul in directory should i create new subparser? But how to create it dynamically?

Comment: And, yes the code is about 350 lines with 6 argument in 5 subparsers. I need to implement it as positional argument. This works fine for all. Only "modul parser" give back an error. I know that's usage tells me, use one of {install...} to use md_script, but i need to run it like ./mainprog.py md_script. I tried to create another subparsers but it failed.

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between subparsers like 'install', and this directory structure.   I would suggest making all arguments `optionals` (with `--` flags) except the subparser one.  That gives you more control over their order and identity.

Comment: It's not depend on me. I want to do that as optional. Quick and easy. But that was main idea make all arguments positional. It's easy to do this that way:
./jsh.py call md_script
But it's still not a way which is required. It's not a positional. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Tools is just a normal directory, where i have all tools that can be used by script, like other script (used by ./jsh.py call script.py) and local module (should be used like ./jsh.py md_script) and that way usege module is a problem. I don't know how to implement creating dynamically subparsers. Or mayby there is anather way?

Comment: It's very close to that what i want. But  in tools/ i can have more modules (md_script is just example) so i need to create dynamically in for loop list of subparsers. And same varible to check if it really is in args and which name of element to use in function. Function is one for all element in list (for all modules). And it is just run the script(module) with argument by subprocess.Popen.

Comment: Maybe all you need is a positional with `choices` - the directory names.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this. It's exactly what I want to.

```
if os.path.isdir(TOOLS_PATH):
   name_arg = next(os.walk(TOOLS_PATH))[1]
   for element in name_arg:
      module_pars = 'parser_'+element
      module_pars = subparsers.add_parser(element, help = 'Modules from tools')
      module_pars.add_argument(element, nargs='?', help=element+' description')
```

I didn't test it, because i dont have a test module, but `./jsh.py md_script` goes into `elif element in args: print('md_script')` and print string. So it looks like it works.
Thanks for all replies.

Edit: I tested it. In add_argument i must change nargs='?' for nargs='*' to catch more than one argument.
And to catch arguments from command line I used this:

```
elif args:
   for element in name_arg:
      if element in args:
         element_arg = sys.argv[2:]
         done_cmd,msg = opt_exec_module(element,*element_arg)
         my_logger(done_cmd,msg)
```

Not very elegant but it works.

Comment: I added an note about that '?' positional named 'element' to my answer.